# How to override interface of an already instantiated object?

Tags: typescript

I have following `@example/core` package.

```js
// @example/core

interface IExample {
  id: number;
}

const example: IExample = {
  id: 1
};

export { example, IExample }
```

In another `@example/extension` package I want to override interface of `example` const variable within the context of the entire package.

```js
// @example/extension

import { example, IExample } from '@example/core';

declare module '@example/core' {
  interface IExample {
    name?: string;
  }
}

// this right now gives error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ITest'.`
console.log(example.name);

// however this works
const newExample: IExample = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'test',
};
console.log(newExample.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance needs to be casted. It was assigned a type previously but the type has been overridden since.

If you move the interface overriding to before you instantiate `example`, it would work.

```
const myExample = example as IExample;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without creating new object, just tricking typescript type checker to treat example from @example/core as {id: number; name: string}?

Comment: You are not creating a new object. You are just creating a new variable which has the right type pointing to the same object. I consider modifying existing interfaces a bad practice, tricking TS doesn't sound like something you want to do since it will be hard for others to understand your hack.

Comment: But you have tricked TS to add a property, it just doesn't retroactively apply to things that have already been typed.